# LocalStorage value problem at refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, local-storage

I have a problem with some currencies in JavaScript, AJAX.
Everything works perfectly, as long as the page is not refreshed.
I need that the html (select, span) to be synchronized with the localstorage.

So at the time of refreshing the page, all data remains as local storage - not in the dom element.

Here is code

```js
/*========= CAMBIO DE DIVISA ==========*/

divisas();

function divisas() {
  $("#cambiarDivisa").append('<option value="USD">$ USD</option>'+'<option value="MXN">$ MXN</option>'+'<option value="EUR">€ EUR</option>')
}

/*========= CAMBIO DE DIVISA ==========*/

$("#cambiarDivisa").change(function(){
  var divisaBase = "USD";
  var divisa = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
 url: "https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q="+divisaBase+"_"+divisa+"&compact=ultra&apiKey=MYAPIKEY",
 type:"GET",
 cache: true,
 contentType: false,
 processData: false,
 dataType:"jsonp",
 success:function(respuesta){
  var divisaString = JSON.stringify(respuesta);
  var conversion = divisaString.substr(11,6);

  localStorage.setItem("respuesta", JSON.stringify(divisaString));
  var respuestadivisa = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("respuesta"));
        var divisavalue = respuestadivisa.substr(6,3);
  console.log("respuesta",divisavalue);
  $(".cambioDivisa").html(divisavalue);
 }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="cambioDivisa">USD</span>
<div class="divisa">
    <select class="align-self-end" name="divisa" id="cambiarDivisa" 
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hint: `$(document).ready(() => {....})` will be called when your page refresh has been finished. You can call `localStorage.getItem("respuesta")` from there and parse the resulting string into your DOM elements

Comment: What exactly can you see when you refresh?

Comment: @CharlieH The page shows USD in the select and in the span.
If i change the select to MXN for example, the select and span changes to MXN, but when i refresh all changes to USD again.

Comment: You will have to load the selected value from the localStorage and set it in the combo box when the page is loaded

Comment: @CharlieH Thanks!
How can I rewrite my code to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You should load the values back to the Options element at the startup of your web page. So, instead of putting the data loading inside ajax callback itself, put it in `$(document).ready`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var respuestadivisa = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("respuesta"));
    var divisavalue = respuestadivisa.substr(6,3);

    console.log("respuesta",divisavalue);

    $(".cambioDivisa").html(divisavalue);

})
```